# Python and Openpyxl - available attributes to format individual cells

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I've looked over the Openpyxl docs, [styles](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html), [cell module](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.cell.cell.html), and [source code](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/openpyxl/cell/cell.html), but I'm not seeing what I need.  Maybe I missed it (as new to Python).

I need to format certain cells within a spreadsheet(ss) differently from the rest of the ss.  Am I able to specify an individual cell as shrink-to-fit, align right, align bottom, font color = grey, etc., while keeping the rest of the SS in the original style?  Is this a [Cell style](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/styles.html) that should be set or is there another resource to see what attributes Openpyxl will allow on an individual cells?

Here's a code snippet where the 'al' variable is working, but not the 'br', and I don't know why.

```
# Cell Alignment
al = Alignment(horizontal='center', vertical='center')
br = Alignment(horizontal='right', vertical='bottom')
for row in sheet['A1':'I43']: 
    for cell in row: 
        if cell == 'Hz':
            cell.alignment = br   #Help: not working
        else:
            cell.alignment = al
```

Thanks,
Phil

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I've got it.  So far, I'm accomplishing individual cell formatting using the NamedStyle object.

Here is my code:

```
# Set 'Named Styles', which are mutable, when need to apply formatting to different cells at once
headerrows = NamedStyle(name='headerrows')
headerrows.font = Font(bold=True, underline='none', sz=12)
headerrows.alignment = al

rooms = NamedStyle(name="rooms")
rooms.font = Font(bold=True, size=12)
rooms.border = Border(left=bold, top=bold, right=bold, bottom=bold)

sheet['A1'].style = rooms
sheet['A2'].style = headerrows
sheet['A3'].style = 'headerrows'
sheet['A4'].style = 'rooms'
```